# Unable to read data sqlite iOS 6

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, ios6

I'm working on a macbook pro, I have my program working fine. When I go to my iMac, I try run it and it give me this error on debugger area (`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`): `Unable to read data`.

I have the right sqlite file on the right folder, I checked many times. I used the same sqlite file to an old version of my app and it worked. The same project that not works on iMac, works on my macbook pro.

I did a reset on iphone simulator, I cleaned my build and always happens the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all `sqlite3_finalize(statement);` that I had on my sqlite methods and now I can access to the DataBase on the other computer.

My question, why I can access to it on my macbook pro with the `sqlite3_finalize(statement);`?

If I don't use it, I can't INSERT anything on the database after to do some SELECT's.

*UPDATE*

I change the `sqlite3_finalize` to `sqlite3_reset` and it worked fine. Now I can INSERT after doing some SELECT's